# Exclude variable from select query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this SQL query;

```
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bsi_roomtype WHERE roomtype_id = ".$_GET['roomid']." ");
```

I use this display details of a room clicked

I have another SQL query on the same page but this time around it doesn't have the WHERE Clause, i use it to run a WHILE LOOP of all the rooms in the database, this however retrieves all records in the `bsi_roomtype` table. What i want is to exclude the current room being selected on the room detail page withe the use of `$_GET['roomid']` hope am clear enough

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually injecting unescaped user data into your queries like that.

Comment: If you want to explode a specific room, you need a WHERE in that query as well: `WHERE roomtype_id != ?`. When you use WHERE, `=` means equal to and `!=` means not equal to. (The `?` is a placeholder for when you're using prepared statements).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson am not using prepared statements so i would really appreciate if you helped me according to my code layout thnx

Comment: got it, i added `bsi_roomtype.roomtype_id != ".$_GET['roomid']."`

Comment: _"am not using prepared statements"_ - I know and that is a _major_ security issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to my problem as suggested by @magnus, i added != on my second query to make

```
$query2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM bsi_roomtype WHERE roomtype_id != ".$_GET['roomid']." ");
```

This excluded one room from the room results